# How to test rendering time (not DomContentLoaded nor onLoad)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, browser, rendering

I need to have a way or tools to test the actual perceived rendering time for the browser to render the entire page to users. Any suggestions?

The reason I ask is because firbug and Yslow only reports the DomContentLoaded and OnLoad time.

For instance, my application reports 547ms (onLoad:621ms) for the contents. But the actual content is rendered around 3 seconds. I know so because I actually counted 1, 2, 3 slowly  from the moment I hit enter in the url field of the browser to the moment when content appears in front of my eyes. So I know 547ms nor 621ms DOES NOT represents the actual time it takes for the page to load.

Not sure if this helps. But my application

1. renders json data on the server side, save the data as a javascript variable along with the rest of the page's html before server returns the entire html to browser
2. page loads Jquery 1.5 and Jquery template
3. jquery code grabs the json data from the variable defined at step 1
4. use jquery template to render the page.

Technically, no Ajax involved here and images on the page are all cached. I don't see firebug downloads any of them.

[Edit]

What i'm trying to figure out is after the firebug reported onLoad time which in my case is 621ms, to the time the page is completed and loaded in my eyes (which is at least 3 seconds), what happened to the 2.4s in between? What took place there? Browser is doing something? Something is blocking? Network? what is it?

Comment: why do you want to count , you can use either firebug , pagespeed or yslow. firebug net panel gives you all the details

Comment: Siri. Like i stated, firebugs and Yslow does not report the accurate time. From the moment I hit enter to when the page loads in front of my eyes, there are a good 3 seconds of blank screen. however, both firebug and yslow report in mili-seconds. As if the page is lighting fast.  To user's eyes however, it's not that fast and that's what i'm trying to capture. Not to firebug nor yslow. But to user's eyes, such the "perceived" time.

Comment: @if this is not your website and if you are working for a company , please try to use some third party company's which does it for you like keynote etc. They perform various kind of loads across the globe and get you the average load time of your page, you can see the complete analysis of where your page is getting slow or fast.

Comment: @siri. Thanks. This is an application I'm developing, so not sure if a third party company can do this?  In addition, even this stackoverflow site. When I hit the homepage, firebug reports 1.21(onLoad 1.2) seconds. But I see my clock moved 4s+ to load the homepage. What's up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Chrome has **excellent** auditing built in. Your results will be skewed because it's one of the fastest browsers right now, but it will give you exact measurements of how long it takes for *Chrome* to render. =)

Comment: Okay. I never tried chrome and just gave it a try and the developer tool is really much better than firebug. I like it! The only problem is that it's too fast! 547ms now down to 100-200ms. I'm not even sure how to monitor it anymore. But I do like the fact it displays three marks. Rendering time. OnLoad Time and DomContentOnLoad time. Much more useful. Thanks

Comment: Glad you like it! I will say though that I still do my day to day development on FireFox's firebug. (Chrome's firebug is getting close, but I still like FF's better =)

Comment: Agreed. The only thing that stops me using Chrome all the time is the way you edit CSS. I really like how in FF you can press enter to complete a CSS rule and jump to the value part, whereas in Chrome you have to use the right arrow key. Not a huge issue, but it annoys me anyway.